# SDL Library to extract red channel

Tags: c++, image-processing, sdl

Is there any specific function in it which can generate the image's red channel to be compared with the original image?

Comment: SDL isn't really an image processing library.

Comment: So what can we do with SDL it? Can it generate the corresponding red channel or green channel ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the pixel data with `surface->pixels` and the pictures Rmask with `surface->format->Rmask`.  Look into bitwise operations to extract the data

```
SDL_Surface* t;
//Code
Uint32* pixels = (Uint32*)t->pixels;
int x = 10 ,y = 10;  //For pixel at 10, 10
Uint32* MyPixel = pixels + ( (y-1) + t->w ) + x;

Uint32 RedOnly = *MyPixel & t->format->Rmask;
```

**Note:** Made a silly mistake and forgot y should be y-1.

`Uint32* MyPixel = pixels + ( (y-1) + t->w ) + x` works like this:

pixels is a pointer, pointing at the first element in an array of Uint32 data.  (32 bit int).  If I do pixels+1, then that says look 1 Uint32 size bytes of memory down the road.  If I want pixel 10,10 in a 2D coordinate system, we need to convert that to a one dimensional linear value.  SDL_Surface pixels are horizontal and linear so it goes:

```
1,2,3,4,5
6,7,8,9,10
```

So `((y-1) * t->w) + x` will get the integer value for the pixel in lineaer form.  For pixel at 2,2 for instance in the case above wehre the width is 5, becomes `((2-1)*5)+2)` which is `7`.  We then take pixels and offset that by 7 (`pixels+7`) which is the address for the Uint32 (7*32 bits) 7 ints from the origin of the array.

`Uint32 RedOnly = *MyPixel & t->format->Rmask` works as this:
Let me assume some random Uint32 for your pixel (0xFF41A401), let's say the picture format is ARGB.  That means your Rmask is 0x00FF0000.
In binary those are

```
*MyPixel = 1111 1111 0100 0001 1010 0100 0000 0001
Rmask    = 0000 0000 1111 1111 0000 0000 0000 0000

//And a bitwise & operation will result in:

RedOnly  = 0000 0000 0100 0001 0000 0000 0000 0000
```

Thus, only the red values remain so you 'erase' all the blue/green information.

Comment: What is t->w? I found this function is it suitable in this case http://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_CreateRGBSurface ?

Comment: t->w is `surface->w` or the width, in pixel count, of the surface.  `surface->h` is height but not needed for this.  `(y+t->w)+x is turning an x,y coordinate into the linear value of the pixel.

Comment: So I must run a for loop but before that I must get the w and h value accordingly rite ? But initially you have got all the pixels in this variable rite ? Then what your are doing here is not clear pixels + ( y + t->w ) + x;

Comment: I know SDL_SURFACE is a structure with all the key items in it. But I dont get your operation here Uint32* MyPixel = pixels + ( y + t->w ) + x; and int RedOnly = *MyPixel & t->format->Rmask;

Comment: That's a completely different question but I'll explain it in my answer.

Comment: thank you now I understand it very detail with the array concept is clear and I know how to retrieve the exact pixel value. So in this case MyPixel will give me the exact value for each pixel and then I apply a red mask to it. How will the & t->format->Rmask; will know to map to this exact pixel ?

Comment: Ok very clear. But normally one pixel will just be represented with just 2 Hex values rite e.g. either FF or BA etc right ? So in this case what will the RMask value be ? Here is my confusion ?

Comment: A pixel is all 8 bytes (2 from R, G, B and A) with a certain endianess. That endianess is represented by the masks.  If your format is ARGB, that is saying in an 8 byte integer, the first two bytes are for the alpha, the second two for the red, the third two for the green, and the last 2 for the blue.  Your mask does that by saying 0x00FF0000.  It is saying which two bytes in your 8 byte integer are the two that correspond to the red color. 
Another way to think about it is a color of full red, Red = 255 or FF would be 0x00FF0000.  The actual int value would be 255^3.

Comment: Ok very clear and very helpful. This apply to any type of image be it .bmp or jgpeg or .png have the same RGBA right ? What doe you mean by 255^3

Comment: So if I need to for every pixel I must run through 2 loops right one for h and one for w ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36735/discussion-between-user2711681-and-chemistpp)